# Issue with Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm in compose mode

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js

I'm developing an outlook web addin.
I want to be able to make "minute of meetings" from an appointment selected either created by me or someone else.
The minute generated an email formatted as I want.
Two use cases :

- The appointment selected from the calendar is one of mine : the appointment display in compose mode
- The appointment selected from the calendar is not one of mine :  the appointment display in read mode

The workflow is :
I select an appointment from calendar, I click on the addin button, the taskpane opens, I fill the form.
Then I click on a button "generate minute" from my taskpane, the email is generated, the taskpane closes automatically.

I want to execute the following code from example to generate the email:

`Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm({ toRecipients: Office.context.mailbox.item.to, // Copies the To line from current item ccRecipients: ["sam@contoso.com"], subject: "Outlook add-ins are cool!", htmlBody: 'Hello <b>World</b>!<br/><img src="cid:image.png"></i>', attachments: [ { type: "file", name: "image.png", url: "http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Cute-Black-Dogs-s.jpg", isInline: true } ] });`

In the second case, the email is properly created and an email opens in a new form.
In the first case I have the error :

```
Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm is not a function
```

From the doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.6&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-mailbox-displaynewmessageform-member(1)
[Outlook Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.6&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-mailbox-displaynewmessageform-member(1))

It seems to be available only in read mode.
This seems to be for me a super restriction and I don't know from the workflow I want to achieve how this could be done.
Does anyone faced this issue ? Does anyone know how could it be solved ?
Thanks

Comment: I think I will change my workflow: from a new email, I will list the meetings made today with the Graph API instead and then read the content of the meeting from this API. The workflow is different with an additional step, but I don’t see any other solution